# Define onClick Events In Another Class

Tags: java, android

Hello :) I have several classes which call the onItemClick event of the same ListView and there is quite a lot of code inside each one, and all the code is the same. I've seen other people define the onClick event in another class, how would i go about doing this?

Any examples or tutorials would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what jpm mean was "implement":

```
public class Blah implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      //do stuff!

    }
  }
```

Comment: ahh okay thankyou, just tried this but how does it know what listview the listener is attached too? do i need to define it somewhere?

Comment: So wherever your ListView is declared, you do:

Blah listener = new Blah();
list.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

The reason this is not done very often in samples is because most of the time you need some information from wherever your listview is declared. (agh, comments are no good for code formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Define a class which extends OnItemClickListener do the stuff you want to do in its onItemClick method and set this listener as the lisviews onItemClickListener...

Comment: Its not possible to extend the OnItemClickListener?

Comment: sorry, implement it...

public class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  //DO STUFF
 }
}